# StandardInputEncoding for ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: c#, windows-services

When i am adding service to windows manually by typing in CMD something like this:

*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\instsrv.exe" "some-pl-char-ąźńćńół" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\srvany.exe"*

... everything is good with service name, but when i try do that in c#:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process myprocess = new Process();

startInfo.FileName = "cmd"; 
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

myprocess.StartInfo = startInfo; 
myprocess.Start();

StreamWriter sw = myprocess.StandardInput;
StreamReader sr = myprocess.StandardOutput;

Thread.Sleep(200);

string command = ...
       ^ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\instsrv.exe" "some-pl-char-ąźńćńół" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\srvany.exe"

sw.WriteLine(command);
sw.WriteLine("exit");

Thread.Sleep(200);

sw.Close();
sr.Close();
```

then name of created service is: some-pl-char-¦č˝Š˝ˇ-

Why there is problem with code page?
There is something like **StandardInputEncoding** for ProcessStartInfo?
My active code page in CMD (using chcp) is 852. (Polish)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>Arguments belongs assigned to the Arguments property and backslashes needs to be escaped by another one. `\` -> `\\`</strike>

Updated:

```
using (var process = new Process())
{
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(852);

    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "cmd";
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.StandardOutputEncoding = encoding;

    process.StartInfo = psi;

    process.Start();

    using (var sr = process.StandardOutput)
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(process.StandardInput.BaseStream, encoding))
    {
        var command = "....";
        sw.WriteLine(command);
        // etc..                   
    }
}
```

Comment: There is slash, not backslash in arguments.

Comment: Its not about the arguments having backslashes. It's about the string. \ is a escape charachter in C# therefore it has a special meaning. Either you escape them with another one like I described or you put a @ in front of your whole string containing backslashes.

Comment: Problem is in encoding, not in string format. If i write to stream only some-pl-char-ąźńćńół, is the same result.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any universal encoding which we can use both for Polish and for other languages (for CMD)? I tried 65001 (UTF8) but it didn't work (e.g.for Russian language).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. Although I was working with VB.net, it fixed my issue. I couldnt run the command unless this was set.

```
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe /c";
```

instead of

```
startInfo.FileName = "cmd";
```

Comment: /c = Carries out command and then terminates, so in my situation will open any exit before stream writer send anything to input.

Comment: It's better to use `cmd.exe` and add `exit` after commands. This way it will not stop before getting output.